# Jackson Don't parse the whole item if certain value is present in JSON Array

Tags: java, json, parsing, serialization, jackson

I am trying to deserialise the following `Json` using `Jackson`.

```
[
  {
    "id" : "abc",
    "deleted": true
  },
  {
    "id" : "def",
  }
]
```

I do not want to create java objects for items that are marked "`deleted":"true"`.

For the above example, output objects for my above JSON structure should be a List with just one object(id:def).

How can I configure jackson to do this?

Comment: The easier would be to parse the whole JSON, then looping on the object or filtering to delete these ones.

Comment: If there are million items that are marked as "deleted":"true", then there would be a million java objects taking up my memory. I don't want to do that.

Comment: you can do benchmark tests, this would be a trade between memory and speed i guess, because i'm not sure that using regex or any string analysis on a JSON string for a million objects would be quick..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jackson to read a stream of JSON data. See [this tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial#jackson-json-streaming-api-example) for details. This will allow you to decide on the fly whether or not to create any object being parsed.

Alternatively, check out [javax.json.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/package-summary.html). This library allows pull parsing which gives you the control you want over parsing your JSON.

In general, the terms you are looking for are "push parsing" and "pull parsing". Use those to find other alternatives to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The tutorial link is empty.

Comment: @Mageshkhanna fixed

Comment: @Mageshkhanna And added more suggestions and details to help you google for more.

Comment: this is neat, i should check if there are such tools for other languages too